# In zsh within a tmux, how do you make page up/down scroll up/down

Tags: zsh, tmux

With my current zsh and tmux (byobu) configuration, typing the page up/down keys will enter `~` in the prompt. What I would like is that

- within a simple shell, page up/down scroll using the terminal history/scrollbar
- within tmux, page up/down make the escape command and use the tmux history navigation for the current window
- within a pager/editor, page up/down scroll up/down use the pager/editor scroll function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually after some research it happens that my current configuration already provide all I need :

- `shift+<page up/down>` will send the corresponding scroll command to the terminal
- `alt+<page up/down>` will send the corresponding scroll command to tmux
- `<page up/down>` will send the corresponding scroll command to the foreground process